# Can't get rid of the original tool bar Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a customized action bar, but when I run the emulator, there's still the dark purple bit on top.
[image]

Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

There will be a code like this in your `theme.xml` file you need to change something in it.

`<style name="Your_App_Name" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DayNightActionBar">`

So you need change the `parent` to this code
`parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: It throws an error for one of the activity :You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @WanjingChen I have edited my answer, implement this and feel free to ask if you got any errors.

Comment: Thank you. I used the same parent before. But it's still there. I'm using Pixel 4 emulator, not sure if this is the problem

Comment: @WanjingChen Are you using dark mode in that emulator?

Comment: No, I'm using the light mode.

Answer (score 0):

1º First. Go to the package:

res-> values-> themes
*In this package you will find two archive themes.xml

2º Second. Open both of the files themes.xml one of the files is for DARK THEME and the other is for LIGHT THEME.

*In the files you will find a tag like this: If you open the file with the Light theme.

```
<style name="Theme.NAMEOFPROJECT" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.LightActionBar">
```

*Change the tag (parent="") with the Theme  in the end of the name with ".NoActionBars".

*After changed wouldbe somthing like this:

```
<style name="Theme.NAMEOFPROJECT" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

3º Third. Go to the package: manifests
*Open the file AndroidManifest.xml and place the theme inside of the application the tag:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.NAMEOFPROJECT"
```

Comment: Thanks, I put it like this:  android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">       But it didn't work

Comment: Sorry! My Explanations wasn't accurate. i'll try to EDIT

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your effort, but it didn't work :(